# remove less sequence count numbers from javascript object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, data-structures, ecmascript-6

I have an object of arrays, each value in object is array of multiple sequence of numbers.

I want to remove those sequences which count is less than 10.

In the given input, the 0th values are having 3 sequences, 2 to 4 is not more than 10 sequence numbers so we need to remove it and remaining 2 sequence count is more than 10.

I have added the space in the below input just for reference, so that you can see there is a sequence break in that array, find the count of that sequence, if the count is less than 10 then remove that sequence.

INPUT:

```
{ '0': [ 2, 3, 4,    7, 8, 9, 10,11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20,     22, 23, 24, 25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32 ],
   '3': [ 0, 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,    15,16,17,18,22,23,24 ] }
```

OUTPUT:

```
{
'0': [7, 8, 9, 10, 11,12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20,     22, 23, 24, 25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32],
'3': [ 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13]
```

I am unable to complete the logic

```
for (var key in emptyMap) {
    let count = [];
    let initialVal = emptyMap(key)[0];
    removeEmptyMap[key] = [];
    for (let i = 1; i < emptyMap(key).length; i++) {

        if ((emptyMap(key)[i] === initialVal + 1)) {

            count[key].push(emptyMap(key)[i])
        } else if (count.pop() < 10) {
            initialVal = emptyMap(key)[i];
        } else {
            initialVal = emptyMap(key)[i];
        }
    }
    console.log()

}
```

Comment: What does `which are having less sequence from the array` mean?

Comment: There are 3 sequences, I need only sequences which count is more than 10.

Comment: A space inside array never represent a sequence break

Comment: How do you define a "sequence"? I only see 2 arrays here. This question is unclear as stated.

Comment: @brk its not space, for representing I have added the space, if you the first object 5,6 are missing. so I called that is 1st sequence. and its count is less than 10 so I have to remove it.

Comment: @ggorlen as soon as sequence is broken in each and every object. then find the count of that sequence and remove that if that sequence count less than  10.

Comment: if I understood correctly, you just want to change the 0th array? When you say that 2 to 4 is not more than 10, you mean that `2+3+4<10` ?

Comment: Ah, I see, so you're defining a sequence as sequential integers in the first one? What is going on with the second one? Looks like you added a line break between `12` and `13` there when it should be one single sequence by your first definition.

Comment: @JoãoPimentelFerreira Nope,  count(2,3,4) => 3 which is less than 10.

Comment: @ggorlen it is just a typo. I will correct them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to create an array of arrays which will contain each sequence. And then return combination of `arrays` whose value is greater than `10`. Apply this method to each `key` of your `obj`

```js
let obj = { '0': [ 2, 3, 4,    7, 8, 9, 10,11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20,     22, 23, 24, 25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32 ],
   '3':
   [ 0, 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,   15,16,17,18,22,23,24 ] }

function getSeq(arr,len){
  let seq = [[]];
  for(let i = 0;i<arr.length;i++){
    seq[seq.length -  1].push(arr[i]);
    if(arr[i] !== arr[i+1] - 1){
      seq.push([])
    } 
  }
  return seq.reduce((ac,a) => a.length < len ? ac: [...ac,...a],[])
}

for(let key in obj){
  obj[key] = getSeq(obj[key],10)
}
console.log(obj)
```

Comment: I would recommend `return seq.filter(a => a.length >= 10).flat()` though

Comment: @Bergi `flat` is not a standard yet. Edge doesn't support it.

Comment: @Bergi flat() is giving error in nodejs, is it another function?

Comment: DPac is right, you will need a polyfill for older platforms - see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat#Browser_compatibility

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you want this. It's a perfect task for [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice).

```js
var obj = 
{ '0': [ 2, 3, 4,7, 8, 9, 10,11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 22, 23, 24, 25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32 ],
'3': [ 0, 1,2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13,   15, 16, 17, 18, 22, 23, 24 ] }

console.log('input', obj)

var sum = 0
for (let i=0; i<obj['0'].length; i++){
  sum += obj['0'][i]
  if (sum > 10) {
    obj['0'].splice(0, i)
    break
  }
}

console.log('output', obj)
```

Comment: I confused with my english, I dont want the sum of the numbers, I want sequence breaking indexes and their indices.

Comment: Once I got the sequence breaking indices, then I want the count of each sequence in each array, which ever sequence is more than 10 then I want that sequences

Comment: what do you mean by "sequence breaking indices"?